# Which parameter and Data Type to set for spatial reference in ArcGIS Python script tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, python-2.7, python-script-tool

I developed a python script for user defined grid and I want to make a tool from this script.

The problem I am facing is to set up parameter for spatial reference.

I used GetParameterAsText function for spatial reference and put 'Spatial reference' in data type while setting the tool in ArcGIS 10.1. It seems that function is not working.

I don't want to ask user to input the Factory code for coordinate rather want to ask them to choose coordinate system as they want to set up for their output feature class.

How can I setup the spatial reference using GetParameterAsText function and ask user to choose their reference system?

Comment: It was ambiguous in your question whether you are writing a Python script (`*.py`) tool in a standard toolbox or a Python toolbox (`*.pyt`) but it sounded much more like the former so I edited your question to make that clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it seems that function is not working'? Is there an error message, is there anything unexpected happening? There is also a 'Coordinate System' data type, have you tried it?

Comment: I tried the option 'coordinate system', 'coordinate system folder', 'spatial reference' separately. Nothing works actually. 'Execute Error' is always shown in dialogue box.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with additional details such as this.